# Rfid tags distance calculate with android

Tags: rfid

Is there any android app that can read rfid tags and locate it?
How distance it works?

I know android can read nfc tags for around 10 cm

Answer (score 0):

Before this gets down voted into oblivion for having nothing to do with programming, it has everything to do with the hardware. The latency and jitter involved with software is too high for timing the round trip to a card and back (for distance), and you'd need multiple antennas to deal with direction.